# How to get the ID's of duplicates rows in a table

Tags: sql

I want to get the IDs of rows with the same name in a Table.

Here is an example of my table, I want to get ALL the IDs of the duplicates names of id n°1. Here are the duplicates value of id n°1 : 1, 3 and 4.

```
ID | name  | size
1  | name1 |  12
2  | name3 |  13
3  | name1 |  12
4  | name1 |  12
5  | name3 |  13
6  | name4 |  18
```

Now this is what I want to have:

```
ID |
1  |
3  |
4  |
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Are the duplicates based on name or name and size?

Comment: What database are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, DB2, etc.) ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff The sizes seem to correlate with the name, in which case, the answer to your question might be that it doesn't matter, but it also might not be wrong to use your current answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple method uses `exists`:

```
select t.id
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.name = t.name and
                    t2.size = t.size and
                    t2.id = 1
             );
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MySQL, then `GROUP_CONCAT` might be helpful here:

```
SELECT name, size, GROUP_CONCAT(ID) AS duplicates
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY name, size
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Most database have a similar analog to `GROUP_CONCAT` in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

This is a faster method than `Exist`

```
SELECT ID 
FROM table
WHERE name IN
(SELECT name FROM table GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Hope this answer your question

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    ID, COUNT(*)
FROM
    table_name
GROUP BY
    name, size
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: You can't select column, if it's not in your group by.

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote your answer is tricky, so I think this is the query to solve the problem the way you described it

```sql
select id 
from TABLE b inner join 
     (select name, size from TABLE where id = 1) a 
     on b.name = a.name and 
        b.size = a.size;
```

the output is

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
+----+
```

Hope I helped!